# Does @resource_name = ResourceName.find(params[:id]) required? in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, controllers

While I was working with one of Rails project, I found following behavior(magical to me):

When I perform `deletion` operation by clicking some button in UI, it invokes controller's destroy method given as:

```
def destroy
  @video = Video.find(params[:id])
  @video.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to videos_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Above code works fine. But curiously, I deleted the line `@video = Video.find(params[:id])`, still the `deletion` operation works.

**Server logs for operation without `@video = Video.find(params[:id])`:**

```
Started DELETE "/videos/52cc08c979478fd5e9000004" for 10.10.10.205 at 2014-01-07 19:32:42 +0530
Processing by VideosController#destroy as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"52cc08c979478fd5e9000004"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (0.8347ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=le collection=users selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"52833e4d79478f53b4000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.8261ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=le collection=assets selector={"_id"=>"52cc08c979478fd5e9000004", "_type"=>{"$in"=>["Video"]}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (1.3051ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 DELETE       database=le collection=assets selector={"_id"=>"52cc08c979478fd5e9000004"} flags=[:remove_first] (0.3262ms)
Completed 204 No Content in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**Server logs for operation having `@video = Video.find(params[:id])`:**

```
Started DELETE "/videos/52cc093179478fcba6000005" for 10.10.10.205 at 2014-01-07 19:33:36 +0530
Processing by VideosController#destroy as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"52cc093179478fcba6000005"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=le collection=users selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"52833e4d79478f53b4000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (1.1661ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=le collection=assets selector={"_id"=>"52cc093179478fcba6000005", "_type"=>{"$in"=>["Video"]}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.8740ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=le collection=assets selector={"_id"=>"52cc093179478fcba6000005", "_type"=>{"$in"=>["Video"]}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.8311ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 DELETE       database=le collection=assets selector={"_id"=>"52cc093179478fcba6000005"} flags=[:remove_first] (0.1166ms)
Completed 204 No Content in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Only difference I found is the pattern of `database requests`:

**1st Case: Without line @video = Video.find(params[:id])**

```
COMMAND -> QUERY -> QUERY -> DELETE
```

**2nd Case: With line @video = Video.find(params[:id])**

```
QUERY -> QUERY -> QUERY -> DELETE
```

Could someone help me to enlighten with the magical behavior behind this? Also, which one is better to use?

Comment: Are there any `before_filter` lines in the controller in question?

Comment: You may have that `@video = Video.find(params[:id])` private and using a before_action

Comment: @CDub: Yes this line 'before_filter :authenticate_user!'. Also 'load_and_authorize_resource' for Cancan

Comment: @Justin: No Justin, I don't have such in private though. Also, searched entire app. Couldn't find it though

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what your answer is here, but i will refer to "Does @resource_name = ResourceName.find(params[:id]) required? in Rails controller"

The simple answer is: YES!

There is nothing in rails that will do that automagically for you. There are however several gems like decent exposure and the like that implement behavior similar to what you describe.

Unless you post the complete controller code including inheritance and mixins and your Gemfile, it's pretty hard to track down the source of your "problem".

It's also likely that there might be a problem with code reloading and that restarting your server instance might show a different behavior.

Comment: I am using 'mongoid' gem. Doesn't this gem doing any trick to this?

Comment: I don't think so, but this should at least be mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Anyway Thanks. Will try to find what is inside my app more :)